# mod_rewrite: url rewrite and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

```
http://example.com/pages/cms/impressum.php
```

and want to get an URL like this:

```
http://example.com/impressum
```

My rewrite Rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^impressum$ /pages/cms/impressum.php [R,L]
```

The Problem is, I can open the url in both ways. I would like a forwarding from /pages/cms/impressum.php to /impressum. If I use [R=301], the second URL which I do not want works. I want to reverse this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect pages/cms/impressum.php to impressum
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+pages/cms/impressum\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /impressum [R=301,L]

# To internally forward impressum to pages/cms/impressum.php
RewriteRule ^impressum/?$ pages/cms/impressum.php [L,NC]
```